# Prove that $|1-x+x^2+x^3| \le \frac{1-|x|^4} {1-|x|}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

> Prove that$$|1-x+x^2+x^3| \le \frac{1-|x|^4} {1-|x|}$$

I see that I should use the triangle inequality to solve for this, but I am not sure how to go about doing so.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $|1 - x  + x^2 + x^3| \le  1 + |x|  + |x|^2 + |x|^3$.